# "Unable to create OpenGL 3.3 context (flags 0, profile 1)"

Tags: c++, opengl

Trying to run any of the [well-known McKesson's tutorials](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) on a friend's laptop results in the aforementioned exception.

I read that in order to run applications which use OpenGL 3.3 you must at least have an ATI HD or Nvidia 8xxx GPU series. He has an ATI HD class graphics processor which eliminates (maybe) this issue. Also, I read that this error may result in having old drivers. He updated his drivers but that didn't solve the problem.

The tutorials are built as said in the [book introduction](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Building%20the%20Tutorials.html) and glsdk is installed.

If more information is needed, say so and I will provide it.

What are the other reasons for this kind of exception? And how can I fix them?

Comment: @NicolBolas Can likely help, he [apparently maintains](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/8240/nicol-bolas) the McKesson tutorials.

Comment: Well, I guess it is up to him. I hope he would share his experience.

Comment: There's not much I can do without access to the laptop in question. If you have hardware capable of running them, and your particular machine cannot due to this error, then update your drivers. If they are as up-to-date as they can be made, and the program still doesn't work... there's not much I can do. The most I can suggest is to verify what version you're able to create with the [OpenGL extension viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/). If it doesn't say 3.3, then your driver probably isn't good enough. How to update it correctly is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for giving me directions! At least I have some clues that the problem is connected with the OpenGL version.

Comment: Apparently, the out-of-date drivers caused this. Thanks to the OpenGL extension viewer we found out that his computer supported OpenGL 3.0. After updating the drivers everything worked fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is most likely the fact that, by default, your system launches most programs using the Intel300 chipset or some other integrated graphics card. The simplest solution is to right-click the .exe which is created after building and select "Run graphics processor" and select the ATI/Nvidia card. You can also change the default chipset to ATI/Nvidia so you dont have to do this everytime you want to test a file but know that it may cause heating/battery problems on your system. This is all in Windows 7 by the way.